# Mysterious dots after scrolling the side content in stackoverflow and meta

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I have been noticing these mysterious dots after scrolling the side content in stackoverflow and meta.  I have tested this in several computers in FireFox.  I dont know wether its the browser or some other element.

[alt text http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/7853/sofdl.jpg](http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/7853/sofdl.jpg)

Comment: oh no, they've been found!!

Comment: Can someone flashy-thing him?

Answer (score 2):

They look like font redraw artifacts, and so are due to either a bug in Firefox (getting the redrawing of the text slightly wrong) or — more likely — a bug in the font (lying about just what its metrics for ascenders and descenders actually are). You see this sort of thing from time to time, and it's frustrating because it's often hard to pin down just where the bug is.

Comment: I've seen it in non-browser code too. Where I've had access to the source and so been able to chase, it's been either because the code was believing the font's metrics or because there was a bug in the font renderer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in Firefox, I've experienced the exact same looking dots in other sites and even my own web work.